# Aptana 3 allow access to local test server?

Tags: windows, networking, browser, ip, aptana

I am developing a website template that I want to work well on a variety of devices. I am using aptana 3 on my windows PC, and using the aptana built in server to preview my work as I go. `http://127.0.0.1:8020/Javascript%20Project/index.html` is the url that appears in the browser.

Is it possible to change my settings (either in aptana or windows) such that another device connected to the local lan can see the aptana server? I have tried substituting 127.0.0.1 for my local ip address in the url but there is no response.

Comment: You would need to replace the 127.0.0.1 with your local IP address - you can find it by running ipconfig in a command prompt and looking at the IPv4 Address.

Comment: I have already tried that, and itgets no response, I need to know if aptana is expecting that or whether windows is block the request.

Comment: Solution: Go to Window > Preferences, then Aptana Studio > Web servers > built in. You can choose whether the built in webserver has 127.0.0.1 or your local IP address. I changed it to my local IP, restarted Aptana, and now my files are available on other devices.